# How to know if a tikz picture is empty

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals

In my code some pictures should be displayed if any condition is satisfied.

The conditional must necessarily be placed within the picture environment.

The question is how to insert a line break in the text ONLY if the picture actually took place.

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\picturexample}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \ifodd#1              % In practice, a PGF/TikZ's check command
    \draw (0,0) circle (1);
  \fi
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newcount\n

\begin{document}

\loop
  \picturexample{\n}%
  \\                    % this should happen only when the picture "exists"
  \advance\n1
\ifnum\n<10\repeat

\end{document}
```

Comment: This belongs to meta-tikz question ^^

Comment: Couldn't you perhaps create a custom `\if` that is set to true if the picture is drawn?

Comment: @JasperHabicht, Yes, I considered that possibility, but I don't want to mess up the code so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store the picture in a box, measure it, and if it has no content then all its dimensions are 0. This does not work for `overlay` pictures, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\picturexample}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \ifodd#1              % In practice, a PGF/TikZ's check command
    \draw (0,0) circle (1);
  \fi
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newcount\n

\begin{document}
\noindent
\loop
  \setbox0\hbox{\picturexample{\n}}%
  \ifdim\dimexpr\wd0+\ht0+\dp0>0pt\relax
    \usebox0\\
  \fi                       % this should happen only when the picture "exists"
  \advance\n1
\ifnum\n<10\repeat
\end{document}
```

Comment: Measuring the box generated by tikzpicture was the idea I had in mind, but I didn't know how to do it. Perfect solution for me.

Comment: By the way, I think it is enough to measure one dimension,